# Dynamically create class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

**I have the following code:**

```
module City
  class Bus < Base
  end

  class BusOne < Bus; end
  class BusTwo < Bus; end
  class BusSixty < Bus; end
  ....
end
```

**My goal is to create this classes dynamically:**

```
  class BusOne < Bus; end
  class BusTwo < Bus; end
  class BusSixty < Bus; end
  ...
```

**That's why I tried:**

```
module City
  class Bus < Base
    DIVISON = [:one, :two, :sixty]
  end

  ....
  Bus::DIVISONS.each do |division|
    class "Bus#{division.capitalize}".constantize < Bus; end
  end
end
```

**But I get this error:**

```
unexpected '<', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.' (SyntaxError)
```

**What do I wrong?**
Thanks

Comment: I think your answer deserves the greenie. Mine is just a variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of John's answer, mainly to show the use of `send` is not essential.

```
module City
  class Bus
    def i_am
      puts "this is class #{self.class}"
    end
  end
end

["BusOne", "BusTwo", "BusSixty"].each do |class_name|
    City.const_set(class_name, Class.new(City::Bus))
end

City::BusOne.new.i_am
this is class City::BusOne

City::BusTwo.new.i_am
this is class City::BusTwo

City::BusSixty.new.i_am
this is class City::BusSixty
```

Answer (score 1):

Works with:

`City.send(:const_set, "Bus#{division.capitalize}", Class.new(Bus))`